# Python gevent: pass multiple arguments to function called via pool.map

Tags: python, gevent

How do I pass multiple arguments to a function I call through pool.map?

My code:

```
import gevent
from gevent.pool import Pool

def process(param1, param2):
    return "dosomething"

pool = Pool(10)
jobs = [('arg1a', 'arg1b'), ('arg2a', 'arg2b')]

# should pass arguments so that it results in these calls
# process(param1=arg1a, param2=arg1b)
# process(param1=arg2a, param2=arg2b)
results = pool.map(process, jobs) # does not work
```

Comment: It can look like `pool.map(unpack(process), jobs)`.
You can vote for add `unpack` decorator to `funcy` library if you want. https://github.com/Suor/funcy/pull/62

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the `gevent.Pool.map` method only allows a single item to be passed as an argument to the function you provide. However, you can code the function to unpack its arguments pretty easily:

```
def process(params):
    param1, param2 = params
    ...
```

Or you could handle the argument unpacking with a lambda expression right in your call to `pool.map`:

```
results = pool.map(lambda args: process(*args), jobs)
```